# IOS app crashes on a line of code if there's no internet connection, how can I prevent this

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crash

The code this and it crashes on "try!", but I don't know how to catch the error and it has it be explicit otherwise it won't work.

```
func downloadPicture2(finished: () -> Void) {          
    let imageUrlString = self.payments[indexPath.row].picture
    let imageUrl = URL(string: imageUrlString!)!
    let imageData = try! Data(contentsOf: imageUrl)
    cell.profilePicture.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
    cell.profilePicture.layer.cornerRadius = cell.profilePicture.frame.size.width / 2
    cell.profilePicture.clipsToBounds = true        
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is don't use `try!` - Use `do/try/catch` and recover from the problem in the `catch` clause.

For example -

```
func downloadPicture2(finished: () -> Void) {          
    cell.profilePicture.image = nil
    if let imageUrlString = self.payments[indexPath.row].picture, 
       let imageUrl = URL(string: imageUrlString) {
        do {
            let imageData = try Data(contentsOf: imageUrl)
            cell.profilePicture.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
        }
        catch {
            print("Error fetching image - \(error)")
        }
    }
    cell.profilePicture.layer.cornerRadius = cell.profilePicture.frame.size.width / 2
    cell.profilePicture.clipsToBounds = true        
}
```

Now you have code that won't crash if the url is invalid or there is no network, but there are still some serious issues with this code.

`Data(contentsOf:)` blocks the current thread while it fetches the data.  Since you are executing on the main thread this will freeze the user interface and give a poor user experience.

Apple [specifically warns not to do this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1413892-init)

> **Important**
>
> Don't use this synchronous initializer to request network-based URLs. For network-based URLs, this method can block the current thread for tens of seconds on a slow network, resulting in a poor user experience, and in iOS, may cause your app to be terminated.

Rather, you should use an asynchronous network operations, such as a [dataTask](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1410330-datatask).

This code operates on `cell` - an external property.  Once you move to asynchronous code you will probably be fetching images for multiple cells simultaneously. You should pass the relevant `cell` to this function to avoid clashes.

The use of the network isn't particularly efficient either; assuming this is part of a table or collection view, cells are reused as the view scrolls.  You will repeatedly fetch the same image as this happens.  Some sort of local caching would be more efficient.

If it is possible to use external frameworks in your project (i.e. your employer doesn't specifically disallow it) then I strongly suggest you look at a framework like [SDWebImage](https://sdwebimage.github.io) or [KingFisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher). They will make this task much easier and much more efficient.